# поиск нужного символа

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqldeveloper

Может просто вопрос, но все же, быстрей будет ответ наверно

```
select regexp_count('8,23,24,88,25,8,8,8,8' , '8') from dual;
```

нужно изменить шаблон, чтобы в исходной строке `'8,23,24,88,25,8,8,8,8'` найти только 8ки, но чтобы 88 в счет не шло, только стоящие отдельно, тут ответ правильный будет 5.
пробовал добавить по символу в начала и конец и написать `'\D 8 \D'`, но тогда съедает некоторые идущие подряд.

Comment: какой у вас диалект SQL? Другими словами - какой тип базы данных?

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)